# Getting Cookies in c#

Tags: c#, cookies, restsharp

So, I am making a GET request to twitter (RestSharp), and I want to collect ALL the cookies and put then in a cookiecollection, first i make the get:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://mobile.twitter.com");

            RestRequest GetAuth = new RestRequest("/login");
            var GetAuth_Response = client.Get(GetAuth);
```

Now, I want to get the cookies, I do this:

```
 CookieCollection Cookies = GetAllCookies(client.CookieContainer);
```

>

```
public static CookieCollection GetAllCookies(CookieContainer container)
{
    var allCookies = new CookieCollection();
    var domainTableField = container.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable");            
    var domains = (IDictionary)domainTableField.GetValue(container);

    foreach (var val in domains.Values)
    {
        var type = val.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().First(x => x.Name == "m_list");
        var values = (IDictionary)type.GetValue(val);
        foreach (CookieCollection cookies in values.Values)
        {
            allCookies.Add(cookies);                    
        }
    }          
    return allCookies;
}
```

Now, when I run the program I get this error:

```
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at this part:

```
var domainTableField = container.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable");
```

Who can help me with this? Thanks ;)

Edit: I also tried to check in a if if it is null, but I still get that same error,

```
if (container.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable") != null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem with this simple code:

```
            foreach (var c in GetAuth_Response.Cookies)
            {
                Cookies.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
            }
```

If you have the same problem, replace the whole GetAllCookies and just use this ^

Answer (score 0):

You may get a null in return. Then getting the name property will raise the exception. You gotta check for null value first.

```
 var domainTableFielObject =       container.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault() ;

If(domainTableFielObject! =null) 
domainTableField =domainTableFielObject. Where(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable");
```

Comment: I still get the same message, but now at **var domainTableFielObject = container.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault();**

Comment: I will start with looking if container is null or not.